# Pass multiple parameters to Router navigation in Angular

Tags: angular

I was able to pass a single parameter to Router navigate in Angular 4 like follow and it works fine.

*`this.router.navigate(['modifyOrder/:labOrderNumber', {labOrderNumber: labOrderNumber}]);`*

But when I tried to pass 2 parameters, it doesn't work.   It didn't take me to modifyOrder page but redirect me to the homepage without giving any error.

```
this.router.navigate(['modifyOrder/:labOrderNumber/:labInvoiceNumber', {labOrderNumber: labOrderNumber, labInvoiceNumber: labInvoiceNumber}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use queryParams property to pass multiple parameters.

```
this.router.navigate(['modifyOrder', {queryParams: {labOrderNumber: labOrderNumber, labInvoiceNumber: labInvoiceNumber}}])
```